# Easiest way to flip the dimension of a movie with python

Tags: python, vectorization, reshape, movie

I have a movie, loaded from a tif file using `skimage.external.tifffile.imread()` into a numpy array with the shape `(frames, width, height)`. What will be the best way to reorder the movie to the shape `( width, height, frames)`?

I can build a function that does this using a for loop, but is there a better way to reshape while avoiding a for loop implementation? Some sort of vectorization of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.moveaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html):

```
movie = np.moveaxis(movie, 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) followed by a [swapaxes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html):

```
import numpy as np

movies = np.zeros((10, 250, 100))

print(movies.shape)
print(np.swapaxes(movies.T, 0, 1).shape)
```

**Output**

```
(10, 250, 100)
(250, 100, 10)
```